# MongoDB Aggregation - How to condition for $set

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am unwinding a lookup joined by `{ preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }` option to include documents whose sizes field is null, missing, or an empty array. But in my case, I need to join nested lookup and the output result is not as I expected.

Specifically, I am being to set a new `buyer` field by the `$set` operator from lookup but if this lookup is null or empty array it will return `[ { } ]` and I don't want that. How can I replace `[ { } ]` with empty array?

The result I got:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "buyers": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003"),
        "buyer": {
          "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000004"),
          "display_name": "Phineas",
          "user_id": "123"
        },
        "post_id": 1,
        "user_id": "123"
      }
    ],
    "content": "content book 1",
    "title": "title book 1"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "buyers": [
      {}
    ],
    "content": "content book 3",
    "title": "title book 3"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "buyers": [
      {}
    ],
    "content": "content book 2",
    "title": "title book 2"
  }
]
```

The result that I expected:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "buyers": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003"),
        "buyer": {
          "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000004"),
          "display_name": "Phineas",
          "user_id": "123"
        },
        "post_id": 1,
        "user_id": "123"
      }
    ],
    "content": "content book 1",
    "title": "title book 1"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "buyers": [],
    "content": "content book 3",
    "title": "title book 3"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "buyers": [],
    "content": "content book 2",
    "title": "title book 2"
  }
]
```

Now you can see my code in the Mongo playground link:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/qiC7FySejxF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing your actual output and MongoDB Playground link, I believe that you miss out the `$unset` stage.

```
{
  $unset: "buyers.buyers"
}
```

While after the `$unset` stage, you can add `$set` stage to update the `buyers` field by filtering the document which is not empty document via `$filter`.

```
{
  $set: {
    buyers: {
      $filter: {
        input: "$buyers",
        cond: {
          $ne: [
            "$$this",
            {}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3hi0gJboiNS)

Comment: Thank you so much! But I want to understand better about your way: `{ $unset: "buyers.buyers" }`. Why do we need twice buyers: `"buyers.buyers"` ? How can i understand it?

Comment: Cause if you check the result generated after `$group` stage, you will need in the `buyers` array, the document contains `buyers` array again. Based on your expected output, you don't need the nested `buyers` field.